# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: Eid_Post_name.massenger_name

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have this issue:

```
"django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: Eid_Post_name.massenger_name
```

And these are my codes.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Name
# Create your views here.

def Home(request):
    name_input = request.POST.get('user_name')

    name_in_model = Name(massenger_name=name_input,)
    name_in_model.save()

    return render(request , 'index.html')
```

and this models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
# Create your models here.

class Name(models.Model):
    massenger_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    action_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.massenger_name
```

and this index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'CSS/style.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="form">
      <form class="row" method="POST">
          <div class="">
            <input type="textarea" class="form-control" placeholder="أكتب أسمك (مثلا/أخوكم عبدالله العتيبي)" id="text_name" name="user_name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" id="button">حمل الصورة</button>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a `Name` row without a `messager_name` which is a required field by default when using `CharField`. You need to make this field nullable:

```py
massenger_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

You need to `makemigrations` and `migrate` to apply your changes. This will allow you to have a `Name` row without a `messager_name`.

Comment: This will make `Name` entries when *visiting* the `Home` page, so likely when only *showing* the form where to enter data.

Comment: thanks alot now its working with me but i dont want null data                                                      what i should do ?

Comment: @datadata: it will create a lot of `Name` entires with `messenger_name` being `NULL`, each time you *visit* the page, not only when you *submit* the form...

Comment: but this not a problem ? because there's a lot of null in database ?

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get), it silences an error when the key is missing, which is the case here.

You should check what method is used and in case of a POST request, handle it properly:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .models import Name
# Create your views here.

def Home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Name.objects.create(massenger_name=request.POST['user_name'])
        return redirect(Home)
    return render(request , 'index.html')
```

In the model, it makes more sense to use [**`auto_now_add=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) for the `action_time`:

```
class Name(models.Model):
    massenger_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    action_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

---

> **Note**: Functions are normally written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, therefore it is
> advisable to rename your function to `home`, not <s>`Home`</s>.

Comment: thank you for your time, can you explain why is the   Name.objects.create(massenger_name=request.POST['user_name'] is useful than my method ?

Comment: @datadata: `.create(...)` will automatically `.save()` the object, and also prevent trying first to update the database, so it saves a query, and is more compact. `POST['user_name']` will raise an error if the key is missing, making the error more descriptive. But that is not the point of the answer. The point is to check with `request.method == 'POST'`.